# cannot find the file specified for containers in windows

Tags: docker

I'm new to docker, sorry if my question is too basic, below is my dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1

COPY dist /app

WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 80/tcp

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ExampleApp.dll"]
```

I got an error:

"exampleApp encountered an error during CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The system cannot find the file specified."

So I created an image and start an instance, it was running OK.

But when I try to copy a file to the container:

`docker cp ./Views/Home/Index.cshtml exampleApp:/app/Views/Home/`
there is a "no such directory" error in powershell, then I ran `docker diff exampleApp` to see the file system, I couldn't find the app directory in the container:
[image]

bur I did specify `app` as working directory inside the container, so why this folder is not appearing in the container?

Answer (score 0):

For a [Docker images for ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/docker/building-net-docker-images?view=aspnetcore-6.0), I would add to your Dockerfile right after the COPY line:

```
RUN dir . /s /b sortorder:N
```

Just to make sure what has been copied, and if the `/app/Views/Home/` does indeed exist.